# Jackson with Spring Boot depth-based serialization

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa

We have in our spring boot (1.5.6) app a classical bi-directional OneToMany hierarchy in our entities, e.g. an `Order` has many `Item`.

```
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<>();
    // getters and setters

} 

public class Item {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JsonBackReference
    private Order order = new HashSet<>();
    // getters and setters

}
```

In our JavaScript-view, which uses rest-controllers to fetch the data, sometimes the `Order` and sometimes the `Items` is the root object. Let's say we have somekind of "Show Order" and another "Show Item" view.

So, if `Order` is the root, we want to know also its children (items) and if an `Item` is the root, we also want to know its parent order.

The serialization obviously would generate an infinite recursion, so we would normally use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` here. 
However, this removes the back-reference (so we have a one-directional serialization here...). We also tried to use `JsonIdentityInfo` - which does not work, because elasticsearch has some problems during the deserialization and we also have some cross-references which will be also replaced by the ids and messes everything up...

Long story short, our idea is now to have somekind of "depth-break":

- When the first serialized object is an `Order`, then its `items`-property should be fully serialized. But for each `Item` the back-reference to `order` should not be serialized (one can say here "the depth of order is 2").
- When the first serialized object is an `Item` then its back-reference `order` is serialized, but the second managed-refrence to items will be ignored.

We tried also JsonView for this, but we cannot dynamically set this value.

Anyone who solved that or has an approach what we can use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` you can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation to suppress serialization of nested properties:

```
public class Item {

   //...

   @JsonIgnoreProperties("items") 
   @ManyToOne
   private Order order = new HashSet<>();

   //...
}
```

Comment: oh hell - that easy - didn't know about this... Thanks!

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you from the future